# Windows Service running under a network account is calling an EXE and running it under system account?

Tags: vb.net, security, windows-services

We have a windows service running under a network account that calls and runs an ActiveX exe.  The exe is running under the local system account, not the network account of the service.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for making the exe run under the network account?

Comment: If you don't know how this miraculous feat occurred, there's little you can do to override it reliably.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Yeah but thats what SO is for :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the function call [CreateProcessAsUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(v=VS.85).aspx).